# Extracting a URL in the query part of another URL

Tags: c#, html, regex

How can I extract a valid URL from a string like this one

```
h*tps://www.google.com/url?q=h*tp://www.site.net/file.doc&sa=U&ei=_YeOUc&ved=0CB&usg=AFQjCN-5OX
```

I want to extract this part: `h*tp://www.site.net/file.doc`,  this is my valid URL.

Comment: Which bit do you what from the string?

Comment: What do you mean with valid? Do you wont to replace the "*" with a "t" or what else?

Comment: Regex is the right way to go. Define the pattern that you want to extract, get the Regex's Matches and pick the one that you require.

Comment: Thanks for your attentions, i edited the question.

Comment: FeliceM, i replaced the t by the star because of the restriction of posting more than two link.. i'm new here! Thank you anyway this informationn can be usefull to me.

Comment: I believe the removal of the * changes what possible solutions are available therefore the * should be included in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add System.Web.dll assembly and use HttpUtility class with static methods.
Example:

```
using System;
using System.Web;


class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.site.net/file.doc&sa=U&ei=_YeOUc&ved=0CB&usg=AFQjCN-5OX");
        Uri doc = new Uri (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (uri.Query).Get ("q"));
        Console.WriteLine (doc);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the protocol as `h*tps`, would `Uri` parse the string correctly?

Comment: Uri parse the string correctly.

Comment: Thats incorrect, tested and got an `Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.` exception.

Comment: Whick version of .net/mono?

Comment: 5, the version is irrelevant, the class hasn't changed. `h*tps` is not a valid protocol so how could it parse it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your other strings can look like, but if your 'valid URL' is between the first `=` and the first `&`, you could use:

```
(?<==).*?(?=&)
```

It basically looks for the first `=` and matches anything before the next `&`.

Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/iM4rN7).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` function

```
    string txt="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.site.net/file.doc&sa=U&ei=_YeOUc&ved=0CB&usg=AFQjCN-5OX";

    txt.split("?q=")[1].split("&")[0];
```

Comment: There are still a bunch of garbage behind.

Comment: ok. 
You can use so:


'txt.split("?q=")[1].split("&")[0];'

Comment: Please edit it into your post.

Answer (score 0):

in this particular case with the string you posted you can do this:

```
string input = "your URL";
string newString = input.Substring(36, 22) ;
```

But if the length of the initial part of the URL changes, and also the lenght of the part you like to extract changes, then would not work.

Comment: this is also usefull thanks:

Comment: You can replace the numbers (36, 22) with int variables and fix the value counting the character to a certain occurrence. My answer is very basic.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi: Please use the Uri class and ParseQuery utility to process the URL.